# How to check if HDF5 is installed?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I have followed instructions from their site. The command `ls /usr/local/hdf5` returns

```
bin include lib share
```

But

```
dpkg -s hdf5
dpkg-query: package 'hdf5' is not installed and no information is available
```

Why?
I have downloaded from here
https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtainsrc.html#conf
and then I have followed the INSTALL file instructions,from make to make install.
 How can I know for sure that HDF5 in installed or not?

Comment: Could you reference the instructions you followed? If you have downloaded the source code and compiled it on your own, it's not common that a debian package is built automatically.

Comment: What distribution are you using? I can see it is Debian based, I just want to know which distro repository you would install it from.

Comment: @ElixirofLove I have downloaded from hdfgropup site,hdf5.1.8.17.tar.gz

Comment: As @Thomas stated above: Since you compiled hdf5 from source, `dpkg` will not know it is installed onto your system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual name of the hdf5 installation package is "libhdf5-dev" (not "hdf5"). Running the following command should return package information.

```
dpkg -s libhdf5-dev
```

If that doesn't give any results, you can check for any hdf5 installation by doing:

```
dpkg -l | grep hdf5
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try running `h5cc -showconfig`:

```
SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:

           HDF5 Version: 1.8.12
```